# Can not satisfy Plone's Unified Installer preflight with openssl

Tags: macos, ssl, openssl, plone

I'm trying to run the Plone Unified Installer (for 4.3.9) on OS X 10.11.3 **without** using the `--without-ssl` option, and I'm getting the following error:

```
Unable to find libssl or openssl/ssl.h.
libssl and its development headers are required for Plone.
Please install your platform's openssl-dev package
and try again.
(If your system is using an SSL other than openssl or is
putting the libraries/headers in an unconventional place,
you may need to set CFLAGS/CPPFLAGS/LDFLAGS environment variables
to specify the locations.)
If you want to install Plone without SSL support, specify
--without-ssl on the installer command line.
```

Also, I'm trying to build openssl from source, without installing it with brew or macports or fink, etc.  I used the instructions [here](http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/openssl/)  to build openssl 1.0.1s.  (The LTS version, 1.0.2, disables SSLv2, which [preflight checks for](https://github.com/plone/Installers-UnifiedInstaller/issues/52), so I went to 1.0.1.)

The [config.log](https://gist.github.com/fulv/ec0e32780c5e3ff1c7bc5193cb56751c) shows that it found the openssl headers ok, so at least that part I'm sure of.  It also shows that it found a whole bunch of symbols from the library files (e.g. libssl.a) and its constituent .o files, so it seems that the library paths are ok, as well.

I'm not sure if I'm reading it right, but this line from config.log

```
preflight:4013: $? = 1
```

seems to indicate that something happened in function `ac_fn_c_try_link`, but I can't figure out what.  Here is the function:

```
# ac_fn_c_try_link LINENO
# -----------------------
# Try to link conftest.$ac_ext, and return whether this succeeded.
ac_fn_c_try_link ()
{
  as_lineno=${as_lineno-"$1"} as_lineno_stack=as_lineno_stack=$as_lineno_stack
  rm -f conftest.$ac_objext conftest$ac_exeext
  if { { ac_try="$ac_link"
case "(($ac_try" in
  *\"* | *\`* | *\\*) ac_try_echo=\$ac_try;;
  *) ac_try_echo=$ac_try;;
esac
eval ac_try_echo="\"\$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: $ac_try_echo\""
$as_echo "$ac_try_echo"; } >&5
  (eval "$ac_link") 2>conftest.err
  ac_status=$?
  if test -s conftest.err; then
    grep -v '^ *+' conftest.err >conftest.er1
    cat conftest.er1 >&5
    mv -f conftest.er1 conftest.err
  fi
  $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: \$? = $ac_status" >&5
  test $ac_status = 0; } && {
     test -z "$ac_c_werror_flag" ||
     test ! -s conftest.err
       } && test -s conftest$ac_exeext && {
     test "$cross_compiling" = yes ||
     $as_test_x conftest$ac_exeext
       }; then :
  ac_retval=0
else
  $as_echo "$as_me: failed program was:" >&5
sed 's/^/| /' conftest.$ac_ext >&5

    ac_retval=1
fi
  # Delete the IPA/IPO (Inter Procedural Analysis/Optimization) information
  # created by the PGI compiler (conftest_ipa8_conftest.oo), as it would
  # interfere with the next link command; also delete a directory that is
  # left behind by Apple's compiler.  We do this before executing the actions.
  rm -rf conftest.dSYM conftest_ipa8_conftest.oo
  eval $as_lineno_stack; ${as_lineno_stack:+:} unset as_lineno
  as_fn_set_status $ac_retval

} # ac_fn_c_try_link
```

Finally, I did use the command `nm -g /usr/local/openssl/lib/libssl.a` to make sure all the needed symbols are there.

Any help in diagnosing this problem greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with Plone-4.1.6-UnifiedInstaller, which I had to install for maintaining older installation.

Managed to install with some simple modifications :

`► iMac@~:ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2h/include/openssl  /usr/local/include/openssl`

So I have earlier installed my **openssl** with **brew** and it is in version :

`► iMac@~:brew info openssl
openssl: stable 1.0.2h (bottled) [keg-only]
SSL/TLS cryptography library
https://openssl.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/.openssl (8B)
  Poured from bottle on 2016-02-15 at 21:07:44
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2f (1,651 files, 11.9M)
  Poured from bottle on 2016-02-15 at 21:07:44
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2g (1,678 files, 12.0M)
  Poured from bottle on 2016-03-07 at 18:32:36
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2h (1,691 files, 12M)
  Poured from bottle on 2016-05-07 at 21:17:01
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2h_1 (1,691 files, 12M)
  Poured from bottle on 2016-05-12 at 23:09:46
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/openssl.rb`

and now PloneUnifiedInstaller seems to compile/install without errors.

Haven't yet tested it, but seems promising and installer ended with **Plone successfully installed ....**.